# Is it true that the Prophet Muhammad foretold the birth of Malik ibn Anas?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, madhhab, maliki

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malik_ibn_Anas):

> According to classical Sunni tradition, the Prophet Muhammad foretold the birth of Malik, saying:
>
> "Very soon will people beat the flanks of camels in search of knowledge and they shall find no one more expert than the **knowledgable scholar of Medina**," and, in another tradition, "The people ... shall set forth from East and West without finding a sage other than the **sage of the people in Medina**."

The [wikipedia page of Malik ibn Anas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malik_ibn_Anas) stated that according to Sunni tradition, the Prophet foretold the birth of Malik.

**Is it true and if it is true, is the Maliki madhab the correct madhab?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a statement of ibn Taymiyah that the madhab of the people of Medina is the closest to truth (Is this really objective?) - See for example fatwa [islamqa #200879](https://islamqa.info/ar/200879) in Arabic. But this doesn't mean the madhab of Malik explicitly. As a-Shafi'i already showed that Malik didn't follow the opinion of the majority of scholars of Medina in several issues and cases.

BTW there are similar ahadith foreseeing Imam abu Hanifa (As-Suyuti quoted some ahadith), and i guess also for a-Shafi'i and Ahamd. These ahadith are rather dai'f. The strongest hadith about Malik (or more exactly a knowledgable scholar from Medina) however appears in Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/41/36) where different Interpretations about whom is meant by the statement are also quoted.

I hope to elaborate later, feel free to ask.

See also this [pro-Maliki](http://www.lamppostproductions.com/the-special-characteristics-of-the-maliki-madhhab-shaykh-muhammad-al-tawil/) post.
And [Can a person take individual opinions from any of the four schools or is it mandatory to follow only one throughout your life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8671/can-a-person-take-individual-opinions-from-any-of-the-four-schools-or-is-it-mand/26391#26391)

Comment: Can you add the source of the hadith I mentioned?

Comment: The website you mentioned [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/41/36) states that the hadith is da'if whereas I found this: "Narrated by Abu Hurayrah by Ahmad, al-Tirmidhi who said it is hasan -- in some manuscripts hasan sahih -- al-Hakim (1:90-91) with three chains, declaring it sahih by Muslim's criterion, al-Bayhaqi in al-Sunan al-Kubra (1:386), etc." (Gibril F. Haddad, The Four Imams and Their Schools [London: Muslim Academic Trust, 2007], p. 121, note 271).                                So which is it da'if, hasan or sahih?

Comment: @Armaan "dai'f" is the classification made by the "editor" of Darussalam not of at-Tirmidhi whom qualified it as حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ (Hadith hassan).